# Please tell me why this occurs. When I am adding border to div tag, it adds extra lines to it. How to solve this problem?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, frontend, tags

HTML markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad maxime accusantium neque id omnis, deleniti nisi, vitae eius quia reprehenderit reiciendis, blanditiis vero eligendi. Reprehenderit blanditiis a odio deleniti mollitia id accusamus! Libero ab corrupti quo rem magnam fuga sunt dolor, repellendus adipisci. Quis soluta, suscipit doloribus inventore distinctio a molestias quas autem qui dolore non est beatae tempora numquam aliquam dolorem ut consequuntur sapiente asperiores, cumque nostrum officia?
            </p>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
    border: solid black 1px;
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 30px;
};
```

[this is the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C8Zy.png)

I have tried universal selector but did not find any help.

Please note that I did this in VS Code.

update: Now I am using the class selector and it works.
But still, the question occurs why I can't use the div tag directly.

Comment: Maybe test your code in a real browser. You won't see that effect there.

Comment: It works on the online compiler, but not in VS Code. Why is that?

Comment: I don't know, but they are obviously poor tools for previewing a site, because there's nothing wrong with the code. It displays just fine in a browser — where it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

The extra lines you see are the combination of the borders and the margins overlapping each other. To fix this issue, you have two options:

Here you have two Options:

1: Remove the margin from div

```
div {
   border: solid black 1px;
   padding: 30px;
}
```

2: Add `box-sizing: border-box;`

```
div {
    border: solid black 1px;
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 30px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**Note:** The `box-sizing: border-box;` property controls how the total width and height of an element are calculated.

Comment: It remains the same, nothing new happened.

Comment: Then it's better to use the [live server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension to render your page to the browser in real-time it might be vs code issue.

Comment: I use the live server extension

Answer (score 0):

you can use :after, :before pseudo to add border.

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
}
.continer:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    border: solid black 1px;
    top: 0;
}
```